# Community's vote count

Tags: discussion, down-votes, community, deleted-posts

If [Community♦](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) owns all the down votes on spam/other deleted posts, why does it seem to have so few down votes?

Current vote count:
Up votes: 236
Down votes: 6

**Update** (today's count):
Up votes: 236
Down votes: 3

Some of [Community♦](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)'s downvotes seem to have disappeared.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how it works, but I think votes on deleted posts are not shown until post undeletion, so while they exist in the database, they may not actually appear. Another possible cause is migrations from other sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Community ♦](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) is very odd... The profile claims to have 0 views. Obviously, *at least* you and I have looked at it. It can offer bounties while having no reputation, and accept answers for people (see the reputation tab on its profile). Therefore, we can assume that Community ♦ has the ability to have reputation, votes, etc. reset and changed at random.

Comment: I think we can safely assume the SO techies have hard-coded for user *Community* to be processed differently to the rest of us, in various contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Precisely. Since it's not really a person, it makes no sense to apply the same rules to it.

Comment: +1 Just FYI: Community owns the open bounties of deleted users (it doesn't ever offer them, AFAIK).  Not sure how the accepts are handled, though.